# org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: Error updating database

Tags: oracle, ejb, weblogic, sql-insert, mybatis

I'm trying to insert a single record to a table using mybatis but encountered java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

dto:

```
public class ClientApplications {
private Integer clientId;
private String appName;
private String appAcctName;
private String cid; 
public Integer getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}
public void setClientId(Integer clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}
public String getAppName() {
    return appName;
}
public void setAppName(String appName) {
    this.appName = appName;
}
public String getAppAcctName() {
    return appAcctName;
}
public void setAppAcctName(String appAcctName) {
    this.appAcctName = appAcctName;
}
public String getCid() {
    return cid;
}
public void setCid(String cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}       
}
```

mybatis-mapper.xml:

```
<insert id="insertClientApplications"
    parameterType="ClientApplications" useGeneratedKeys="false">
    insert
    into client_applications (client_id, app_name,
    app_acct_name, cid, start_date, created_by,
    eca_created_date, updated_by, updated_date) values
    (#{clientId}, #{appName}, #{appAcctName}, #{cid}, trunc(sysdate),
    'cltSvc', sysdate, 'cltSvc', sysdate);
</insert>
```

mybatis-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD SQL Map Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>      
<typeAliases>        
    <typeAlias alias="ClientApplications" type="com.xyz.dto.ClientApplications"/>
</typeAliases>

<plugins>
    <plugin interceptor="com.xyz.dao.mybatis_3_2_8.MybatisLoggingInterceptor"/>         
</plugins>  
<environments default="default">
    <environment id="default">
    <transactionManager type="MANAGED"/>            
        <dataSource type="JNDI">
            <property name="data_source" value="jdbc/client-svc"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="mybatis-mapper.xml"/> 
</mappers>  
</configuration>
```

this is how i'm setting params and calling the insert method :

```
ClientApplications cltApps = new ClientApplications(1214114, 'CA', '1231111', '1423423SSD'); 
mapper.insertClientApplications(cltApps);
```

org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

#### The error may involve com.xyz.insertClientApplications-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: insert   into client_applications (client_id, app_name,   app_acct_name, cid, start_date, created_by,   created_date, updated_by, updated_date) values   (?, ?, ?, ?, trunc(sysdate),   'cltSvc', sysdate, 'cltSvc', sysdate);

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:200)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionManager.java:357)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy335.insert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager.insert(SqlSessionManager.java:236)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:57)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy337.insertEntClientApplications(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mybatis.cdi.SerializableMapperProxy.invoke(SerializableMapperProxy.java:56)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy337.insertClientApplications(Unknown Source)
at com.xyz.AddRelationships.determineAppAcctId(AddRelationships.java:193)
at com.xyz.AddRelationships.addRelationships(AddRelationships.java:72)
at com.xyz.ProcessAddRelationships.run(ProcessAddRelationships.java:15)
at com.xyz.UniqueProcessor.process(UniqueProcessor.java:45)
at com.xyz.UniqueProcessor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
at com.xyz.Poller.checkEip(Poller.java:97)
at com.xyz.Poller.timerTimeout(Poller.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.invokeTimeoutMethodInternal(Jsr250Metadata.java:373)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.proceed(LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.java:126)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor179.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.invokeLifecycleMethod(Jsr250Metadata.java:388)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.proceed(LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.java:121)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.proceed(LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.java:150)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.InterceptionMetadata.invokeTimeoutMethod(InterceptionMetadata.java:626)
at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EjbComponentCreatorImpl.invokeTimer(EjbComponentCreatorImpl.java:71)
at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.InjectionBasedEjbComponentCreator.invokeTimer(InjectionBasedEjbComponentCreator.java:185)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.invokeTimeoutMethod(BaseEJBManager.java:199)
at weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl.timerExpired(TimerImpl.java:338)
at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:290)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4901)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:119)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor156.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:59)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy292.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor259.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49)
at com.paychex.hrs.traceability.dao.mybatis_3_2_8.MybatisLoggingInterceptor.intercept(MybatisLoggingInterceptor.java:41)
at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy344.update(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
... 52 more
```

Comment: It looks like the parameters are not being bound properly.  Check the value of `#{clientId}` etc. in your code.

Comment: this is how i'm setting and calling the insert method ClientApplications cltApps = new ClientApplications(1214114,
     'CA', '1231111', '1423423SSD');
   mapper.insertClientApplications(cltApps);

Comment: No.  Don't add this information in unreadable comments.  Edit your question instead.

Comment: Remove the semicolon `;` at the end of the statement.